# Ruby/Rails and R Compatibility, Statistical Packages

Tags: ruby, r, compatibility

We currently have an R-based graph and are hoping to integrate this into our Rails application. A couple of questions:

1) Is RSRuby still valid as an option? The last gem update and the majority of articles on it are from 2009, so I worry about its maintainability, especially as Ruby 2 has come out (we're still on Ruby 1.9.3 for the record).
2) Are there solid statistical options available, or even native, to Rails that compare to the robustness of R?

Any tidbits or how you've approached this in the past are welcome.

Comment: How is the graphic implemented? Is it generated on page view? Or is it something that you can run every once in a while (via chron, for example).

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, thanks for the reply. The graphic in the Rails app will be generated on page view.

Comment: What I'm trying to get to here is that it may be easier (and less "expensive") to pre-generate the images with a source R script and chron, and then refer to their location. If it's a relatively stock plot, the google plot api may be a better (and significantly less expensive) route.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has given us the push we needed. Happy to accept your answer if you want the additional rep. Will close in a couple of days otherwise

Comment: My comments are not an answer, in any way, to the substance of your actual question. :)

Comment: Haha, well again, very much appreciate your comments, then. Extremely helpful solution that would have taken us a bit to come around to otherwise.

Comment: Although, it may be a good idea to document your methodology so that passerby can "see" the option you selected. SO has high visibility via google search, so others may be interested in understanding your method.